# Class and Function in Python

Tags: python, function, class

I've got the results of 30 different tests. These results vary by level of Education. Dusuk mean low, orta mean medium, yuksek mean high. I need to get the level of education and the score of the test from the user. I'm supposed to give you the results of 30 different tests.The Program requires the user to find and select mean and standard deviation values according to the level of Education entered. The user also needs to take the value of the input score and perform a mathematical operation. I want him to calculate (average - score) /standard deviation and print it on the screen. You'll see the code I wrote below. I wanted to write using class and function but I can't get any output. Can you help? Thank you so much.

```
class Testler():
def __init__(self,ortdusuk:int, ortorta:int, ortyuksek:int, stddusuk:int, stdorta:int, stdyuksek:int):
    self.ortdusuk = ortdusuk
    self.ortorta = ortorta
    self.ortyuksek = ortyuksek
    self.stddusuk = stddusuk
    self.stdorta = stdorta
    self.stdyuksek = stdyuksek

def inputlar (self, egitim, skor):
    egitim = input("Egitim duzeyini dusuk, orta ya da yuksek olarak belirtiniz:")
    print(inputlar(str(egitim)))
    skor = input("Test skorunu giriniz: ")
    print(inputlar(int(skor)))


def math (self, outputdusuk, outputorta, outputyuksek):
    outputdusuk = (ortdusuk - skor) / stddusuk
    outputorta = (ortorta - skor) / stdorta
    outputyuksek = (ortyuksek - skor) / stdyuksek


def sorgula (self, outputdusuk, outputorta, outputyuksek, dusuk, orta, yuksek):
    if egitim == dusuk:
        print(sorgula(self.outputdusuk))
    elif egitim == orta:
        print(sorgula(self.outputorta))
    elif egitim == yuksek:
        print(sorgula(self.outputyuksek))
```

Comment: Where do you actually initiate an object and call the method?

Comment: In the definition of `sorgula` the variable `egitim` is used but doesn't seem to be defined.